# Behavior of the "this" keyword with polymorphism and runtime binding

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I have the following polymorphic class hierarchy and would like to understand how the `this` keyword is evaluated when using dynamic binding.

```
public class A {
  void f(C c) {}
}

public class B extends A {
  void f(C c) {
    System.out.println("B.f(C)");
    c.f(this);
    C.g(this);
  }
}

public class C {
  static void g(A a) { System.out.println("C.g(A)"); }
  static void g(B b) { System.out.println("C.g(B)"); }
  void f(A a) { System.out.println("C.f(A)"); }
  // void f(B b) { System.out.println("C.f(B)"); }
}

public class D extends C {
  void f(A a) { System.out.println("D.f(A)"); }
  void f(B b) { System.out.println("D.f(B)"); }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  A a = new B();
  C c = new D();
  a.f(c);
}
```

With the method `C.f(B b)` commented out, the main method prints:

```
B.f(C)
D.f(A)
C.g(B)
```

Why is the `this` keyword in the `B.f(C c)` method evaluated to `A` when calling the non-static function `f` and evaluated to `B` when calling the static function `g`?

Furthermore I have observed that if I uncomment the method `C.f(B b)`, the output changes to:

```
B.f(C)
D.f(B)
C.g(B)
```

Why is in this case the type of the `this` keyword evaluated to `B` for the non-static and static method?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-method-dispatch-runtime-polymorphism-java/

Comment: Beware of the difference between method overloading and overriding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two steps when deciding which method to call. One step (which overload?) happens at compile time, the other step (which implementation?) happens at runtime.

---

#### `C.f(B b)` commented out case

The compiler will do the first step, deciding which overload to call. There is only one overload of `c.f`:

```
void f(A a) { System.out.println("C.f(A)"); }
```

So the compiler selects that. `this` is of compile time type `B`, so it can be implicitly converted to `A`.

Why doesn't the compiler see the `f(B b)` method in `D`? Because the compiler doesn't know that `c` is *actually* an instance of `D`, so it will only look in the `C` class, since `c` is of compile time type `C`.

At runtime, it is found that there are two implementations of `f(A a)` - one in class `C` and one in class `D`. Since the runtime knows that `c` is an instance of `D`, `D.f(A a)` will be called.

#### `C.f(B b)` uncommented case

This time, the compiler finds two overloads of `c.f` to call:

void f(A a) { System.out.println("C.f(A)"); }
  void f(B b) { System.out.println("C.f(B)"); }

The compiler will choose the method with the most *specific* parameters. "Most specific" means that a type is the farthest down the inheritance tree. This means that `f(B b)` will be selected.

At runtime, the implementation in `D` will be called for the same reason as the first case.